# OS X: Two-machine GDB debugging results in frequent hangs

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, kernel-extension

I'm debugging a KEXT on a target system running 10.8.5 from a host (also running 10.8.5) using GDB over ethernet. On the target, the `nvram boot-args` settings are:

```
debug=0x115 -v pmuflags=1
```

However, even with `pmuflags=1`, I still see the debugger hang when I single-step from a breakpoint. This problem happens fairly frequently and the only resolution I have is to power-cycle the target and start over.

What could be causing these hangs and what else can I do to keep them from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this from a developer who is running into the same situation:

"When I asked about single-step lockups in kernel debug targets 4 years ago, there was no feedback from anyone at Apple. The lockups happen. Others experience them. Maybe noone at Apple single steps in ethernet GDB kernel debug sessions. I played around with firewire debugging back when I first experienced this, but gave up for reasons I can no longer remember. I have gotten used to less when it comes to kernel debugging on OSX."

Looks like single-stepping through gdb is far from perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, single-stepping doesn't work that well. Neither does repeated break/continue/break/continue, etc. You'll also find that you will sometimes end up on a different thread because the breakpoint that single-stepping creates doesn't discriminate between threads, which makes it fairly useless in some situations.

I've found the kdp interface a lot more useful for inspecting state at a particular point of execution, than for watching things change. In many cases, you can substitute kprintf+fwkpfv for single-stepping though. Oh, and you can break to the debugger in your code, e.g. in a custom assert() implementation, using `__asm("int $3");` as in userspace.